# SharePoint information hosted in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, microsoft

So quick question,  where in the SharePoint_Config DB would I expect to find the SharePoint server that is being used?

[SQL SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Imw7.jpg)

Currently getting the "Could not connect to the configuration database" when trying to launch SharePoint.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to serverfault, where answers are not given until the person asking for them has done a certain amount of research. for example i could find a lot of [Microsoft tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+change+database+server) for the exact request

Answer (score 0):

Could you please follow the steps provided on [this troubleshooting guide](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/cannot-connect-to-the-configuration-database/)?

1. Verify SQL Server services are running using SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Verify the farm account credentials are not expired or changed.
3. Verify the account that runs the SharePoint application pool does have sufficient permissions to connect to the configuration database.
4. Verify on the properties of the Configuration Database that the database is not set on read-only mode.
5. Verify max degree of parallelism on SQL Server is set to 1